# Shell w/ fork & execvp

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple shell (for fun) that parses the command from a the command line and uses execvp to execute the command. My question is- am I on the right track? Is what I'm doing make any sense structurally?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"


#ifdef PARSE_H
#define PARSE_H
#define BUF_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char input[BUF_LEN];  //get the command
    char cmdName[20];
    strcpy(cmdName, argv[1]);

    // ignoring CTRL+C interrupt from keyboard
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

    while(1){                               // create the shell
        printf("$ ");
        fgets(input, BUF_LEN, stdin);
        parse(input, argv);
        int newpid = fork();                //fork child
        if(!(newpid == 0)){                 // this is the parent
            int wait_rv;
            int a;

            wait_rv = wait(&a);
        }
        else if(newpid == 0){
            execvp(cmdName, argv);
        }
    }
}

static void parse( char* input, char* argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;

    // fgets reads the \n, so overwrite it
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';

    // get the first token
    argv[i] = strtok( input, " " );

    // get the rest of them
    while( ( argv[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ") ) );
}

#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but it seems you are looking for https://codereview.stackexchange.com If not please take the [tour] of this site here.

Comment: I don't get why that `cmdName` is initialized (and never reassigned) with the first parameter of your shell... It should be initialized with the first token parsed by `parse`. Also, `parse` is not going to work like this - `argv` is passed by value, so the result of reassigning its element isn't going to be visible from the outside. Besides, I wouldn't recycle the `argv` array from the shell command line arguments - you cannot know if it's big enough, and recycling it is going to add confusion anyway. Finally, if your shell is going to have builtins you are not going to `fork` unconditionally.

Comment: Convention to use `fork` is `iRet=fork(); if (0 == iRet)  { // child} elseif(-1==iRet) {//errorcase} else {//parent handling}`